# Sistema de Log perdendo dados, como usar Threads?

Tags: delphi, thread, multithreading

Atualmente possuo um sistema de nível médio onde preciso gravar Log detalhado de tudo que acontece no sistema, a Empresa que é dividida em Departamentos faz auditoria de tudo que acontece através dos Log!

Tenho uma `Procedure` bem simples que faz o acesso ao Arquivo e o edita passando a nova linha do Log que será gravado:

```
procedure frmFuncoes.GravaLogDetalhado(Texto: String);
var
  Arquivo : TextFile;
begin
  AssignFile(Arquivo, 'D:\Sistema\Log\LogDetalhado.txt');
  Append(Arquivo);
  Writeln(Arquivo, Texto);
  CloseFile(Arquivo);
end;
```

Bom, quando eu preciso gravar Log de de algum evento eu adiciono da seguinte forma:

```
procedure frmDetCliente.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  GravaLogDetalhado('Abriu Detalhes do Clientes');
  ...
  ...//Blocos e blocos de códigos
  ... 
  GravaLogDetalhado('Clicou em Editar Cliente');
  ...//Blocos e blocos de códigos
  ...
  GravaLogDetalhado('Fechou Detalhes do Clientes');
end;
```

O problema que enfrento é que a Empresa não quer um Log para cada departamento, e sim um Log único gravado no Servidor, começa a complicar quando as possibilidades aparecem:

- Almoxarifado iniciou lançamento de itens no Banco de
  Dados.
- Finanças começou a gerar a folha de pagamento.
  ....

Essa `Procedure` recebe também um SQLMonitor que envia o comando SQL também para o Log todos os `Insert`, `Update` e etc que pode ser executado em um Banco de Dados.

Andei lendo e me parece que a saída para evitar perda de dados (LOG) é usar Threads. Por onde começar ?

Comment: Você pergunta **Por onde começar?** e depois escreve que **As respostas atuais não contêm detalhes suficientes.**. E as repostas são todas negativadas. Talvez seria o caso de você direcionar melhor a pergunta.

Comment: Basta observar a data da Pergunta, depois a data que foi postado as respostas negativadas, em seguida observar a data que ofereci a recompensa! Depois observar que foi editada por Terceiro! Hoje falta 2 dias e já existe respostas melhores que as de antes e com capacidade de receber o voto Correto! E das negativadas, nenhum voto é meu!

Comment: O repositório dos dados tem que ser um arquivo texto? o Sistema é Desktop, procede?

Comment: Sim, deve ser texto, não interessa a extensão, csv, txt ou log tanto faz! E sim, é desktop!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tempos precisei de uma solução para algo semelhante a seu problema, não tão grande quanto mas bem parecido!
A solução no entanto foi usar varias Thread para resolver, como não sou desenvolvedor Delphi tive que comprar um sistema e pagar pela sua manutenção!

Demorei postar a resposta desde que editei essa pergunta pois estava procurando contato de um antigo amigo que resolveu o problema mencionado!

Segue as implementações que ele fez para mim!

**Unit unt_funcaoLog**

```
type
  {Classe responsável pela geração de LOG!}
  TGeraLog = Class
    private
      FCritical : TCriticalSection;

      Const C_ARQUIVO = '.\arquivo_log.txt';
      {Indica o arquivo em que o LOG será gerado, no caso, no mesmo diretório do executável!}
      Class var FInstance : TGeraLog;
      {Instância única do objeto!}
      Class function GetInstancia: TGeraLog; static;
      {Método responsável por instanciar o objeto singleton!}
    public
      procedure AfterConstruction; override;
      procedure BeforeDestruction; override;
      procedure GeraLog(Const AReferencia: String; Const AData: TDateTime; Const ATextoLog: String);
      {AReferencia..: Referência à Thread chamadora.}
      {AData........: Data e Hora da geração do LOG.}
      {ATextoLog....: Texto a ser escrito no arquivo de LOG.}
      function TryGeraLog(Const AReferencia: String; Const AData: TDateTime; Const ATextoLog: String): Boolean;
      {Método que TENTA gerar uma nova linha de LOG!}
      {AReferencia..: Referência à Thread chamadora.}
      {AData........: Data e Hora da geração do LOG.}
      {ATextoLog....: Texto a ser escrito no arquivo de LOG.}
      Class property Instancia: TGeraLog read GetInstancia;
      {Referência à instância singleton!}
  end;

implementation

{ TGeraLog }

procedure TGeraLog.AfterConstruction;
begin
  inherited;
  DeleteFile(Self.C_ARQUIVO);
  Self.FCritical := TCriticalSection.Create;
end;

procedure TGeraLog.BeforeDestruction;
begin
  inherited;
  Self.FCritical.Free;
end;

procedure TGeraLog.GeraLog(const AReferencia: string; const AData: TDateTime; const ATextoLog: string);
var
  _arquivo   : TextFile;
  sNovaLinha : String;
begin
  sNovaLinha := Format('%s|%s|%s', [AReferencia, DateTimeToStr(AData), ATextoLog]);

  {Entra na seção crítica!}
  Self.FCritical.Enter;
  try
    AssignFile(_arquivo, Self.C_ARQUIVO);
    if (FileExists(Self.C_ARQUIVO)) then
    begin
      Append(_arquivo);
    end
    else
    begin
      Rewrite(_arquivo);
    end;

    Writeln(_arquivo, sNovaLinha);

    CloseFile(_arquivo);
  finally
    {Sai da seção crítica}
    Self.FCritical.Release;
  end;
end;

Class function TGeraLog.GetInstancia: TGeraLog;
begin
  if not(Assigned(FInstance)) then
  begin
    FInstance := TGeraLog.Create;
  end;
  Result := FInstance;
end;

function TGeraLog.TryGeraLog(const AReferencia: String; const AData: TDateTime;
  const ATextoLog: String): Boolean;
var
  _arquivo   : TextFile;
  sNovaLinha : String;
begin
  sNovaLinha := Format('%s|%s|%s', [AReferencia, DateTimeToStr(AData), ATextoLog]);

  {Tenta entrar na seção crítica!}
  Result := Self.FCritical.TryEnter;
  if (Result = True) then
  begin
    try
      AssignFile(_arquivo, Self.C_ARQUIVO);
      if (FileExists(Self.C_ARQUIVO)) then
      begin
        Append(_arquivo);
      end
      else
      begin
        Rewrite(_arquivo);
      end;

      Writeln(_arquivo, sNovaLinha);

      CloseFile(_arquivo);
    finally
      {Sai da seção crítica}
      Self.FCritical.Release;
    end;
  end;
end;

initialization

finalization

  TGeraLog.Instancia.Free;

end.
```

**Unit unt_diversasThreads**

```
type
  TDiversaThread = Class(TThread)
    private
      FReferencia    : String;
      FDescricaoErro : String;

    public
      procedure Execute; override;
      {Rotina a ser executada pelo Thread que eventualmente gerará uma linha no arquivo de LOG!}

      property Referencia: String read FReferencia write FReferencia;
      {Referência que será escrito no arquivo de LOG para sabermos de onde veio a linha!}

      property DescricaoErro: String read FDescricaoErro;
  end;

implementation

{ TDiversasThread }

procedure TDiversaThread.Execute;
var
  bGeraLog : Boolean;
begin
  inherited;
  try
    {Loop enquanto o Thread não for finalizado!}
    while not (Self.Terminated) do
    begin
      {Aqui definimos um time para diminuir o consumo de CPU}
      Sleep(10);

      {Sorteia um número e verifica se o resto da divisão por dois é zero!}
      bGeraLog := (Random(1000000) mod 2) = 0;

      if (bGeraLog = True) then
      begin
        {Chama o método de geração de LOG!}
        TGeraLog.Instancia.GeraLog(Self.FReferencia, Now, 'O rato roeu a roupa do Rei de Roma');
      end;
    end;
  except
    on E: EInOutError do
    begin
      Self.FDescricaoErro := Format('Erro de I/O #%d - %s', [E.ErrorCode, SysErrorMessage(E.ErrorCode)]);
    end;
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      Self.FDescricaoErro := Format('(%s) - %s', [E.ClassName, E.Message]);
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Estou gravando os log nessa chamada:

`TGeraLog.Instancia.GeraLog('QUEM_ENVIOU_LOG', Now, 'TEXTO_QUE_DESEJA');`

Segundo meu amigo a função **TryGeraLog** é mais eficiente quando existe vários acesso ao mesmo arquivo, mas como não é meu caso eu uso apenas a GeraLog.

Comment: +1 Testando a função/Thread TryGeraLog adaptada com uns adicionais aqui esta se saindo bem nos testes! de 500 envios apenas 2 se perdeu e foi queda na conexão (a perca aconteceria em qualquer ambiente).

Answer (score 4):

Pelo que pude entender, seu sistema deve estar sendo executado em mais de um computador simultaneamente.
Nesses casos, a tentativa de escrever em arquivo por mais de um processo resulta em perda de dados devido ao lock do arquivo.
Outro agravante é que quando um arquivo é aberto por um compartilhamento ele demora mais para ser liberado para escrita por outro computador da rede. Pior ainda se for samba ...

Então você deve sempre utilizar um mecanismo mais eficiente para escrever log.
Eu utilizaria um serviço no estilo **MESSAGE QUEUE** para escrever um mesmo log a partir de diferentes origens. Uma tabela no Banco de dados resolveria isso e facilitaria demais no futuro consultar as ocorrencias no LOG.

Outra forma de escrever um mesmo log de diferentes origens é utilizar o mecanismo de log do Windows que é capaz de escrever no log de eventos também facilitando a pesquisa.

[Este artigo](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/40404) é muito bom para ver como fazer um mecanismo de log escrever em um computador remoto (servidor)

Para escrever no logo do sistema local, pode-se utilizar o código abaixo

```
uses SvcMgr; // Adicione ao seu Uses 

procedure frmFuncoes.GravaLogDetalhado(Texto: String, EventType: DWord = 1);
begin
  with TEventLogger.Create('NOME_APLICACAO') do
  begin
    try
      LogMessage(Texto, EventType);
    finally
      Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

e no seu código utilizaria

```
procedure frmDetCliente.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  GravaLogDetalhado('Abriu Detalhes do Clientes', EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE);
  ...
  ...//Blocos e blocos de códigos
  ... 
  GravaLogDetalhado('Clicou em Editar Cliente', EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE);
  ...//Blocos e blocos de códigos
  ...
  GravaLogDetalhado('Fechou Detalhes do Clientes', EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE);
end;
```

Dessa forma você passa o controle de escrita para o Sistema.

Comment: Exato, é executado em diversas maquinas diferentes e em alguns casos ate mesmo em mais locais diferentes e inclusive a casos de 2 sistemas na mesma maquina! E sim a base de dados é em servidor Linux (temos uma versão Web que funciona em alguns trabalhos de campo pela empresa) Já tentamos usar o próprio Windows para gerar os log, por incrível que pareça deu mais problemas que o processo manual, ele demora a gravar e em alguns casos fica desordenado o horário dos eventos! +1 pela ajuda e o ótimo artigo!

Comment: Como disse na resposta, eu partiria para usar um mecanismo de fila de mensagens. Ele tem varios beneficios por ser um mecanismo assincrono que permite escrita simultanea de diversas origens. Não importa se vai usar threads ou não. Sempre que acontecer tentativa de escrita simultanea vai ter dead lock. Infelizmente para Delphi eu não conheço nenhuma lib gratuita para usar MQs.

Answer (score 1):

Não acredito que Threads para cada evento seria uma solução, ja que vários departamentos poderão acessar o mesmo arquivo de log ao mesmo tempo. Acredito que surgira outros problemas.

A melhor saída na minha opinião seria cada departamento criar seu proprio log durante um processo e ao final deste processo uma thread é criada para montagem de um log geral usando os dados deste log local.

Seria mais ou menos nessa ordem:

1 - Processo iniciado pelo usuario e todas as acoes sarão salvas em um arquivo local.

2 - Ao fim do processo criar uma thread para acesso exclusivo ao arquivo de log "global".

Um exemplo seria

```
begin
  if FileExists(Filename) then
    fstm := tFileStream.Create(Filename, fmOpenReadWrite or fmShareExclusive)
  else
    fstm := tFileStream.Create(Filename, fmOpenReadWrite or fmShareExclusive or fmCreate) end;
```

Isso garantira que somente uma thread ira acessar o arquivo.

Voce pode controlar as outras threads para aguardar para o acesso ao arquivo.

Comment: Criar um log para cada departamento já foi testado, o problema acontece da mesma forma quando existe a tentativa de gravar no log principal.+1 pela pela bem vinda ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

A melhor solução neste caso é desenvolver um sistema separado que escute uma porta via UDP no computador onde o arquivo de log está. Quando recebe uma requisição de registro de log, esta aplicação coloca esta requisição numa fila de espera, enquanto que um TTimer verifica a lista de tempos em tempos e grava as requisições na ordem correta.

Na sua aplicação principal você coloca uma procedure que faz essa chamada ao aplicativo de log via UDP pelo IP do servidor. É uma alternativa simples e que acabará com todos os problemas de bloqueio de arquivo e perda de dados.

Answer (score -4):

Creio que uma solução talvez até mais simples seja gravar esse log em uma tabela no banco de dados principal, ou até mesmo em um banco de dados separado, dependendo do volume de dados que vão ser gerados por esses logs. Pelo que entendi seriam vários usuários rodando o seu executável em computadores diferentes, certo? Nesse caso, a utilização de threads para proteger o acesso ao arquivo não ajudaria muito, não.

Answer (score -4):

Eu não aconselho o uso de Threads (minha opinião), após usar várias eu chegue a conclusão que não vale a pena porque você não consegue debugar é quando as vezes param de funcionar sem uma explicação lógica, o melhor mesmo é você ter uma unit de funções onde os processos vão sendo feitos sem prejudicar a manipulação da tela aberta.
Estou postando um exemplo de como você poderia resolver o seu problema.

```html
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 GravaLogDetalhado('Almoxarifado','Abriu Detalhes do Clientes');
end;

procedure TForm1.GravaLogDetalhado(Departamento,Texto: String);
 var
  Arquivo  : String;
  BkpLog   : TextFile;
begin
  Arquivo  := 'C:\Test.txt';

 if not(FileExists(Arquivo)) then
    begin
    AssignFile(BkpLog,Arquivo );
    //Um novo arquivo em disco com o nome atribuído à variável "Arquivo" é
    //criado e preparado para processamento, um ponteiro de arquivo é colocado no início do arquivo criado.
    //Caso o arquivo a ser criado já exista, esta instrução apaga o arquivo para criá-lo novamente.
    Rewrite(BkpLog);
    CloseFile(BkpLog);
     end
  else
    begin
        AssignFile(BkpLog, Arquivo);
      //Abre um arquivo texto existente para estendê-lo (saídas adicionais). Caso o arquivo não exista,
      //esta instrução provocará um erro de Entrada/Saída (Input/Output).
        Append(BkpLog);
        Writeln(BkpLog, Departamento + ' - ' + DateTimeToStr(now) + ' : ' + Texto );
        CloseFile(BkpLog);
  end;
end;
```